# No class def found error when building maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, querydsl

I am using `querydsl` and when I am trying to build maven project it fails:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.codegen.model.Type

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like: com.mysema.codegen.model.Type  is some code /classes in your codegen module.  You need add them into your classpath for the compile .

Comment: @SeanH if Im searching for it in whole project and there is no place where it exists

Answer (score 3):

You can try a new version

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding below dependencies into your maven pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.codegen/codegen -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.codegen</groupId>
    <artifactId>codegen</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Then compile the project again.